# Powershell to encrypt text file with password or string

Tags: command-line, powershell, encryption, passwords

I'm running a shared computer with command prompt access, and I want to be able to encrypt and decrypt a text file from a powershell script, with a unique user-identified password. This way the file could not be opened without that password. I tried to use [this module](https://github.com/pldmgg/misc-powershell/tree/master/MyModules/EncryptDecrypt), however it seems to need something called a certificate. All I want is a powershell script that could be called with something like `-Encrypt -File "Path\To\File" -Password -"12345"` (and something similar to decrypt it). Does such a tool exist? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: This should help you https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/ even though it's about encrypting passwords, i think it should also fit to encrypt a whole text file

Comment: I’m very new to powershell and I’m not sure how to put all of that together. I normally use batch code but figured powershell would have something like what I’m looking for. I’m not seeing where one would put in a password in any of those scripts, to clarify I’m not trying to “generate” or “save” passwords, I’m trying to password protect a text file.

Comment: You can find the module in the powershell gallery if you are still looking for it: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/EncryptDecrypt

Answer (score 2):

The following PowerShell does what you need. ([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20200318045131/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/EncryptDecrypt-files-use-65e7ae5d)*)

### Description:

> This PowerShell module includes 3 cmdlets to create an AES key, encypt a file, and decrypt a file.

### Example usage:

```
#Create Key 
$key = New-CryptographyKey -Algorithm AES 
 
#Encrypt the file 
Protect-File '.\secrets.txt' -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource 
 
#Decrypt the file 
Unprotect-File '.\secrets.txt.AES' -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource

The full module code:

function New-CryptographyKey()
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
Generates a random cryptography key.

.DESCRIPTION
Generates a random cryptography key based on the desired key size.

.PARAMETER Algorithm
Algorithm to generate key for.

.PARAMETER KeySize
Number of bits the generated key will have.

.PARAMETER AsPlainText
Returns a String instead of SecureString.

.OUTPUTS
System.Security.SecureString. New-CryptographyKey return the key as a SecureString by default.
System.String. New-CryptographyKey will return the key in plain text as a string if the -AsPlainText parameter is specified.

.EXAMPLE
$key = New-CryptographyKey
This example generates a random 256-bit AES key and stores it in the variable $key.

.NOTES
Author: Tyler Siegrist
Date: 9/22/2017
#>
[CmdletBinding()]
[OutputType([System.Security.SecureString])]
[OutputType([String], ParameterSetName='PlainText')]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1)]
    [ValidateSet('AES','DES','RC2','Rijndael','TripleDES')]
    [String]$Algorithm='AES',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [Int]$KeySize,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='PlainText')]
    [Switch]$AsPlainText
)
    Process
    {
        try
        {
            $Crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm)
            if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('KeySize')){
                $Crypto.KeySize = $KeySize
            }
            $Crypto.GenerateKey()
            if($AsPlainText)
            {
                return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Crypto.Key)
            }
            else
            {
                return [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Crypto.Key) | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Error $_
        }
        
    }
}

Function Protect-File
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
Encrypts a file using a symmetrical algorithm.

.DESCRIPTION
Encrypts a file using a symmetrical algorithm.

.PARAMETER FileName
File(s) to be encrypted.

.PARAMETER Key
Cryptography key as a SecureString to be used for encryption.

.PARAMETER KeyAsPlainText
Cryptography key as a String to be used for encryption.

.PARAMETER CipherMode
Specifies the block cipher mode to use for encryption.

.PARAMETER PaddingMode
Specifies the type of padding to apply when the message data block is shorter than the full number of bytes needed for a cryptographic operation.

.PARAMETER Suffix
Suffix of the encrypted file to be removed.

.PARAMETER RemoveSource
Removes the source (decrypted) file after encrypting.

.OUTPUTS
System.IO.FileInfo. Protect-File will return FileInfo with the SourceFile, Algorithm, Key, CipherMode, and PaddingMode as added NoteProperties

.EXAMPLE
Protect-File 'C:\secrets.txt' $key
This example encrypts C:\secrets.txt using the key stored in the variable $key. The encrypted file would have the default extension of '.AES' and the source (decrypted) file would not be removed.

.EXAMPLE
Protect-File 'C:\secrets.txt' -Algorithm DES -Suffix '.Encrypted' -RemoveSource
This example encrypts C:\secrets.txt with a randomly generated DES key. The encrypted file would have an extension of '.Encrypted' and the source (decrypted) file would be removed.

.EXAMPLE
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Files' -Recurse | Protect-File -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource
This example encrypts all of the files under the C:\Files directory using the key stored in the variable $key. The encrypted files would have the default extension of '.AES' and the source (decrypted) files would be removed.

.NOTES
Author: Tyler Siegrist
Date: 9/22/2017
#>
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='SecureString')]
[OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo[]])]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PSPath','LiteralPath')]
    [string[]]$FileName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2)]
    [ValidateSet('AES','DES','RC2','Rijndael','TripleDES')]
    [String]$Algorithm = 'AES',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3, ParameterSetName='SecureString')]
    [System.Security.SecureString]$Key = (New-CryptographyKey -Algorithm $Algorithm),
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3, ParameterSetName='PlainText')]
    [String]$KeyAsPlainText,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)]
    [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]$CipherMode,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=5)]
    [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]$PaddingMode,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=6)]
    [String]$Suffix = ".$Algorithm",
    [Parameter()]
    [Switch]$RemoveSource
)
    Begin
    {
        #Configure cryptography
        try
        {
            if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'PlainText')
            {
                $Key = $KeyAsPlainText | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
            }

            #Decrypt cryptography Key from SecureString
            $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Key)
            $EncryptionKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR))

            $Crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm)
            if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('CipherMode')){
                $Crypto.Mode = $CipherMode
            }
            if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('PaddingMode')){
                $Crypto.Padding = $PaddingMode
            }
            $Crypto.KeySize = $EncryptionKey.Length*8
            $Crypto.Key = $EncryptionKey
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    }
    Process
    {
        $Files = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FileName
    
        ForEach($File in $Files)
        {
            $DestinationFile = $File.FullName + $Suffix

            Try
            {
                $FileStreamReader = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($File.FullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
                $FileStreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($DestinationFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)

                #Write IV (initialization-vector) length & IV to encrypted file
                $Crypto.GenerateIV()
                $FileStreamWriter.Write([System.BitConverter]::GetBytes($Crypto.IV.Length), 0, 4)
                $FileStreamWriter.Write($Crypto.IV, 0, $Crypto.IV.Length)

                #Perform encryption
                $Transform = $Crypto.CreateEncryptor()
                $CryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream($FileStreamWriter, $Transform, [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write)
                $FileStreamReader.CopyTo($CryptoStream)
    
                #Close open files
                $CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                $CryptoStream.Close()
                $FileStreamReader.Close()
                $FileStreamWriter.Close()

                #Delete unencrypted file
                if($RemoveSource){Remove-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName}

                #Output ecrypted file
                $result = Get-Item $DestinationFile
                $result | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SourceFile –Value $File.FullName
                $result | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Algorithm –Value $Algorithm
                $result | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name Key –Value $Key
                $result | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name CipherMode –Value $Crypto.Mode
                $result | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name PaddingMode –Value $Crypto.Padding
                $result
            }
            Catch
            {
                Write-Error $_
                If($FileStreamWriter)
                {
                    #Remove failed file
                    $FileStreamWriter.Close()
                    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationFile -Force
                }
                Continue
            }
            Finally
            {
                if($CryptoStream){$CryptoStream.Close()}
                if($FileStreamReader){$FileStreamReader.Close()}
                if($FileStreamWriter){$FileStreamWriter.Close()}
            }
        }
    }
}

Function Unprotect-File
{
<#
.SYNOPSIS 
Decrypts a file encrypted with Protect-File.

.DESCRIPTION
Decrypts a file using a provided cryptography key.

.PARAMETER FileName
File(s) to be decrypted.

.PARAMETER Key
Cryptography key as a SecureString be used for decryption.

.PARAMETER KeyAsPlainText
Cryptography key as a String to be used for decryption.

.PARAMETER CipherMode
Specifies the block cipher mode that was used for encryption.

.PARAMETER PaddingMode
Specifies the type of padding that was applied when the message data block was shorter than the full number of bytes needed for a cryptographic operation.

.PARAMETER Suffix
Suffix of the encrypted file to be removed.

.PARAMETER RemoveSource
Removes the source (encrypted) file after decrypting.

.OUTPUTS
System.IO.FileInfo. Unprotect-File will return FileInfo with the SourceFile as an added NoteProperty

.EXAMPLE
Unprotect-File 'C:\secrets.txt.AES' $key
This example decrypts C:\secrets.txt.AES using the key stored in the variable $key. The decrypted file would remove the default extension of '.AES' and the source (encrypted) file would not be removed.

.EXAMPLE
Unprotect-File 'C:\secrets.txt.Encrypted' -Algorithm DES -Key $key -Suffix '.Encrypted' -RemoveSource
This example decrypts C:\secrets.txt.Encrypted using DES and the key stored in the variable $key. The decrypted file would remove the extension of '.Encrypted' and the source (encrypted) file would be removed.

.EXAMPLE
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Files' -Recurse | Unprotect-File -Algorithm AES -Key $key -RemoveSource
This example decrypts all of the files under the C:\Files directory using the key stored in the variable $key. The decrypted files would remove the default extension of '.AES' and the source (encrypted) files would be removed.

.NOTES
Author: Tyler Siegrist
Date: 9/22/2017
#>
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='SecureString')]
[OutputType([System.IO.FileInfo[]])]
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [Alias('PSPath','LiteralPath')]
    [string[]]$FileName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [ValidateSet('AES','DES','RC2','Rijndael','TripleDES')]
    [String]$Algorithm = 'AES',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, ParameterSetName='SecureString')]
    [System.Security.SecureString]$Key,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=3, ParameterSetName='PlainText')]
    [String]$KeyAsPlainText,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]$CipherMode = 'CBC',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=5, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]$PaddingMode = 'PKCS7',
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=6)]
    [String]$Suffix, #Assigning default value in code due to it not processing ".$Algorithm" properly when Algorithm is ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName
    [Parameter()]
    [Switch]$RemoveSource
)
    Process
    {
        #Configure cryptography
        try
        {
            if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'PlainText')
            {
                $Key = $KeyAsPlainText | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
            }

            #Decrypt cryptography Key from SecureString
            $BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Key)
            $EncryptionKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR))

            $Crypto = [System.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricAlgorithm]::Create($Algorithm)
            $Crypto.Mode = $CipherMode
            $Crypto.Padding = $PaddingMode
            $Crypto.KeySize = $EncryptionKey.Length*8
            $Crypto.Key = $EncryptionKey
        }
        Catch
        {
            Write-Error $_ -ErrorAction Stop
        }

        if(-not $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Suffix'))
        {
            $Suffix = ".$Algorithm"
        }

        #Used to store successfully decrypted file names.
        $Files = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FileName

        ForEach($File in $Files)
        {
            #Verify file ends with supplied suffix
            If(-not $File.Name.EndsWith($Suffix))
            {
                Write-Error "$($File.FullName) does not have an extension of '$Suffix'."
                Continue
            }

            $DestinationFile = $File.FullName -replace "$Suffix$"

            Try
            {
                $FileStreamReader = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($File.FullName, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
                $FileStreamWriter = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($DestinationFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create)

                #Get IV from file
                [Byte[]]$LenIV = New-Object Byte[] 4
                $FileStreamReader.Seek(0, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) | Out-Null
                $FileStreamReader.Read($LenIV,  0, 3) | Out-Null
                [Int]$LIV = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($LenIV,  0)
                [Byte[]]$IV = New-Object Byte[] $LIV
                $FileStreamReader.Seek(4, [System.IO.SeekOrigin]::Begin) | Out-Null
                $FileStreamReader.Read($IV, 0, $LIV) | Out-Null
                $Crypto.IV = $IV

                #Peform Decryption
                $Transform = $Crypto.CreateDecryptor()
                $CryptoStream = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream($FileStreamWriter, $Transform, [System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode]::Write)
                $FileStreamReader.CopyTo($CryptoStream)

                #Close open files
                $CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
                $CryptoStream.Close()
                $FileStreamReader.Close()
                $FileStreamWriter.Close()

                #Delete encrypted file
                if($RemoveSource){Remove-Item $File.FullName}

                #Output decrypted file
                Get-Item $DestinationFile | Add-Member –MemberType NoteProperty –Name SourceFile –Value $File.FullName -PassThru
            }
            Catch
            {
                Write-Error $_
                If($FileStreamWriter)
                {
                    #Remove failed file
                    $FileStreamWriter.Close()
                    Remove-Item -LiteralPath $DestinationFile -Force
                }
                Continue
            }
            Finally
            {
                if($CryptoStream){$CryptoStream.Close()}
                if($FileStreamReader){$FileStreamReader.Close()}
                if($FileStreamWriter){$FileStreamWriter.Close()}
            }
        }
    }
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function New-CryptographyKey
Export-ModuleMember -Function Protect-File
Export-ModuleMember -Function Unprotect-File
```

*The source link was taken from gjpio's answer. This new answer includes the actual code, rather than depending on the source link. I originally suggested this as an edit to gjpio's answer, but my edit was rejected with the feedback that it should instead be an answer of it's own.

Comment: You linked to the exact same script, that was submitted over 5 years ago, and the answer was updated 2 years ago. I am going to issue a downvote for submitting duplicate information instead of improving the existing answer. Including the script would have been easily been approved.

Comment: "Including the script would have been easily been approved."
I tried to but it was rejected for some reason. The exact comments from the reviewers was: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

Comment: The edit proposal in this case was wrong in my opinion. Since you were given bad advice I won't hold it against you.

Comment: Thank you. I completely agree with your comments. It doesn't make sense to create a new answer. I don't know how to contest the review. Is that even possible?

Comment: I am going to take it upon myself to fix that answer, since editing an answer to include the script or module from an external resource provided it's properly cited and quoted, is absolutely the suggested and accepted practice.  **The author should have never submitted the answer the way it was.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148375/discussion-between-alex-oakley-and-ramhound).

Comment: I am just going to downvote the original answer and upvote this answer.  **I don't have the time to fix an the low quality link-only answer.**

Comment: I remember approving the edit https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1213533 but people here are too automatic with edit rejections quite often. Make sure to make it more clear that you are adding content from a link rather than your own (which is a good reason to reject most of the time).

Answer (score 1):

This script from the PS gallery might do the trick;
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/EncryptDecrypt-files-use-65e7ae5d

UPDATE: the gallery has been removed. I cant find a migrated version anywhere but the webarchive has a copy:
https://web.archive.org/web/20200318045131/https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/EncryptDecrypt-files-use-65e7ae5d

Comment: This uses a secure key instead of a password. I don't see how I could use this to set it with a password.

Comment: A password is a key that you type in. With a certificate or a key you just pass those in as well. You could make you password a file to use as well, though don't that with securing it as well.

Comment: The link is dead.